# Could "extraordinary few exceptions" be correct?

Tags: adverbs, meaning

In his 1991 book, historian J.B. Russel writes:

> with extraordinary few exceptions no educated person ... believed that the earth was flat

Should *extraordinary* be an adverb, or could this sentence be interpreted as if there are few exceptions, and those are extraordinary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an error to me: it should either be

> With extraordinarily few exceptions...

or, with the alternative interpretation that you suggest (that those exceptions that there are are extraordinary):

> With few, extraordinary, exceptions...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it could be a typo on the part of the author or publisher, or it could be deliberate use of an adjective where an adverb should go. But don't forget that *few* can be a pronoun as well as an adjective:

> Few would argue that the world is flat.

In this sentence *few* is definitely functioning as a pronoun.

It could be in this sense that the author is consciously or unconsciously using it. Which leads me to believe that this may not be an error but a stylistic choice. I also think it could mean what you think it means in your second interpretation: there are few exceptions and they are extraordinary.

Comment: Are you sure *few* is functioning as a pronoun/noun here? I agree it definitely does in your example, but in the question I'm having a hard time making it into a noun because however I parse it I always seem to end up with "exceptions" left over... the best I can do to make this sentence grammatical for me is to assume he's using *extraordinary* as an adverb in a similar way to how some people use *mighty* as in "there were mighty few...".

Comment: Why would he _deliberately_ use an adjective instead of an adverb?